# Calculating price returns within groups in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have a dataframe `df` which has following information:

```
DateTime    MDate       Fwd    Type
1/4/2010    2/1/2010    61.17   A
1/5/2010    2/1/2010    59.73   A
1/6/2010    2/1/2010    62.2    A
1/7/2010    2/1/2010    61.1    A
1/8/2010    2/1/2010    60.25   A
1/11/2010   2/1/2010    57.12   A
1/12/2010   2/1/2010    57.35   A
1/13/2010   2/1/2010    58.12   B
1/14/2010   2/1/2010    57.12   B
1/15/2010   2/1/2010    59.38   B
8/1/2013    5/1/2014    57.67   B
8/2/2013    5/1/2014    57.25   B
8/3/2013    5/1/2014    57.9    B
8/4/2013    5/1/2014    59.25   B
8/5/2013    5/1/2014    57.67   B
```

I want to create the following:

```
DateTime    MDate      Fwd    Type   pctChange 
1/4/2010    2/1/2010    61.17   A   
1/5/2010    2/1/2010    59.73   A    (0.02)
1/6/2010    2/1/2010    62.2    A    0.04 
1/7/2010    2/1/2010    61.1    A    (0.02)
1/8/2010    2/1/2010    60.25   A    (0.01)
1/11/2010   2/1/2010    57.12   A    (0.05)
1/12/2010   2/1/2010    57.35   A    0.00 
1/13/2010   2/1/2010    58.12   B   
1/14/2010   2/1/2010    57.12   B    (0.02)
1/15/2010   2/1/2010    59.38   B    0.04 
8/1/2013    5/1/2014    57.67   B   
8/2/2013    5/1/2014    57.25   B    (0.01)
8/3/2013    5/1/2014    57.9    B    0.01 
8/4/2013    5/1/2014    59.25   B    0.02 
8/5/2013    5/1/2014    57.67   B    (0.03)
```

I want to isolate the time series based on groups `(MDate, Type)` and calculate the `pctChgange`

So, in my example above, first group is created as follows. It has same `MDate` and `Type` are same for all rows:

```
DateTime    MDate      Fwd    Type   pctChange 
1/4/2010    2/1/2010    61.17   A   
1/5/2010    2/1/2010    59.73   A    (0.02)
1/6/2010    2/1/2010    62.2    A    0.04 
1/7/2010    2/1/2010    61.1    A    (0.02)
1/8/2010    2/1/2010    60.25   A    (0.01)
1/11/2010   2/1/2010    57.12   A    (0.05)
1/12/2010   2/1/2010    57.35   A    0.00
```

I calculated `pctChange` as `59.73/61.17 - 1 = (0.02)`

I was thinking of implementing some version of:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['MDate', 'Type'], values=['Fwd'], aggfunc=someFunction)
```

I am not able to figure what function I can implement for `someFunction`

Comment: I fail to see what's the difference between what you want and what you generated in your example. What does 'isolate the time series based on groups' mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
df[['MDate', 'DateTime']] = df[['MDate', 'DateTime']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, infer_datetime_format=True))

df['pctChange'] = df.groupby(['MDate', 'Type'])['Fwd'].transform(pd.Series.pct_change).fillna('').apply(lambda x: '({0:.2f})'.format(-x) if x < 0 else '{0:.2f}'.format(x) if x else x)

df

#     DateTime    Fwd      MDate Type pctChange
#0  2010-01-04  61.17 2010-02-01    A          
#1  2010-01-05  59.73 2010-02-01    A    (0.02)
#2  2010-01-06  62.20 2010-02-01    A      0.04
#3  2010-01-07  61.10 2010-02-01    A    (0.02)
#4  2010-01-08  60.25 2010-02-01    A    (0.01)
#5  2010-01-11  57.12 2010-02-01    A    (0.05)
#6  2010-01-12  57.35 2010-02-01    A      0.00
#7  2010-01-13  58.12 2010-02-01    B          
#8  2010-01-14  57.12 2010-02-01    B    (0.02)
#9  2010-01-15  59.38 2010-02-01    B      0.04
#10 2013-08-01  57.67 2014-05-01    B          
#11 2013-08-02  57.25 2014-05-01    B    (0.01)
#12 2013-08-03  57.90 2014-05-01    B      0.01
#13 2013-08-04  59.25 2014-05-01    B      0.02
#14 2013-08-05  57.67 2014-05-01    B    (0.03)
```

The first line converts `MDate` and `DateTime` to `datetime` as I wasn't sure if they are in correct format.

Comment: Thanks for answer. What is this ({0:.2f}) for ?

Comment: It is formatting the floating point number to show 2 decimal places.

Comment: I was missing the transform function that you applied .. great help ..thanks again